# Retrieving Stripe metadata and process it

Tags: django, cookies, django-views, checkout

I am sending cart data from the cookies to Stripe and retrieving it, but I am unable to find a solution to process it correctly.

Please help!

I am learning Django and wanted to save the cart items of non-logged users into the cookies and send it to Stripe, as Metadata.
From there retrieve it and if the checkout is completed to process the order, but I am unsuccessful to process the data that is retrieved to be able to save the order.

Stripe Checkout Session:

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    domain_url = 'http://localhost:8000/checkout/'

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
    else:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        total = data['form']['total'].replace('.', '')
        email = data['form']['email']
        first_name = data['form']['first_name']
        last_name = data['form']['last_name']
        customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(
            email=email
        )
        customer.first_name = first_name
        customer.last_name = last_name
        customer.save()

    cart_info = cart_details(request)

    cart_items = cart_info['cart_items']
    order = cart_info['order']
    items = cart_info['items']

    print(items)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            shipping_address_collection={
                "allowed_countries":
                    ["US", "CA", "NL", "GB"]
                },
            client_reference_id=request.user.id,
            customer_email=request.user.email,
            success_url=domain_url + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancelled/',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='payment',
            line_items=[
                {
                    'name': 'Kenpachi Katana Store',
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'amount': int(order.get_cart_total*100),
                }
            ]
        )
        return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
    else:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            shipping_address_collection={
                "allowed_countries":
                    ["US", "CA", "NL"]
                },
            **metadata=[items]**,
            client_reference_id=customer.id,
            customer_email=email,
            success_url=domain_url + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancelled/',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='payment',
            line_items=[
                {
                    'name': 'Kenpachi Katana Store',
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'amount': total,
                }
            ]
        )
        return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
```

Terminal Output with the Cookie Cart variable:

```
print(type(items))
```

<class 'list'>

And:

```
[{'product': 

`{'id': 1, 
'name': 'Sasuke Katana', 
'price': Decimal('270.00'), 
'imageURL': '/media/1_ccbb983f-a35d-40f8-8efb-dc55db02ad8f_700x.webp'}, 
'quantity': 1, 
'get_total': Decimal('270.00')}, 
`
{'product': 
{'id': 3, 
'name': 'Zoro Katana', 
'price': Decimal('260.00'), 
'imageURL': '/media/1_466b0afb-d483-4a32-b0bb-89388aeccaa4_700x.webp'}, 
'quantity': 1, 
'get_total': Decimal('260.00')
}]
```

And it easy to loop through it

```
for item in items:
        print(item)
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQrjT.png)

After the the order is completed, I retrieve the Stripe Session to fulfill the order

```
@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    endpoint_secret = settings.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload,
            sig_header,
            endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(
            event['data']['object']['id'],
            expand=['line_items'],
        )

        stripe_metadata = session['metadata'].setdefault('0')
        print(stripe_metadata)
        print(type(stripe_metadata))

        # Fulfill the purchase...

        #   TODO: drill down on the metadata from stripe
        transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
        total = session['amount_total']
        customer_id = session['client_reference_id']
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer,
            complete=False
        )
        order.transaction_id = transaction_id

        if (total / 100) == int(order.get_cart_total):
            order.complete = True

        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            address=session['shipping']['address']['line1'],
            city=session['shipping']['address']['city'],
            state=session['shipping']['address']['state'],
            zipcode=session['shipping']['address']['postal_code'],
            country=session['shipping']['address']['country'],
        )
        order.save()
        print('Order was added to the database')
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Terminal Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7R73.png)

What would be the best option to retrieve it in the same format, to be able to iterate through the products of the cart.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

GitHub repo with the cookie cart function:
https://github.com/GeorgianF/Kenpachi-P5-CI/blob/main/cart/utils.py

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
stripe_metadata = json.loads(str(stripe_metadata))
```

to convert string to JSON format